# copy multiple ranges with Union to Word document without blank cells between the ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy multiple ranges to a word document. I got it to work with a union of ranges:

```
Set rng1 = Worksheets(2).Range("E2:G8")
Set rng2 = Worksheets(2).Range("E22:G23")
Set multipleRange = Union(rng1, rng2)
    multipleRange.Copy

wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
wd.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
```

The problem I can't fix is that it copies the cells between the ranges too as blank cells in the word table. It copies E9:G21 too which is not wanted.
Is there a way to either not copy those cells or maybe delete them once they are copied over? (That might destroy the formatting thought)
PS: This is only the first step, later I want to copy the same range of cells from each sheet to a new page of the word document, but I don't think that will be a problem when this runs, just added this for context.

Thanks
M.S

Comment: `1` Copy the range to a temp sheet. `2` Redefine your new range `3` Copy that range to Word document `4` Delete the tempsheet

Comment: In my answer below, I am using `Worksheets(2)` as an example. Please avoid using `Worksheets(2)`. The position can change anytime. Use the sheet codename or the actual name.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment above, try this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim multipleRange As Range, copyrng As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range

    Dim tmpsheet As Worksheet
    Dim ColName As String
    Dim totCols As Long, totRows As Long

    Set rng1 = Worksheets(2).Range("E2:G8")
    Set rng2 = Worksheets(2).Range("E22:G23")

    Set multipleRange = Union(rng1, rng2)

    Set tmpsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    multipleRange.Copy tmpsheet.Range("A1")

    For Each rngArea In multipleRange.Areas
        If rngArea.Columns.Count > totCols Then totCols = rngArea.Columns.Count
        totRows = totRows + rngArea.Rows.Count
    Next rngArea

    ColName = Split(Cells(, totCols).Address, "$")(1)

    Set copyrng = tmpsheet.Range("A1:" & ColName & totRows)

    copyrng.Copy

    wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    wd.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tmpsheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, but I got a solution by myself before looking here again:

As Storax said you have to paste the Ranges one by one, which I did with some really ugly code, but it works:

```
Set rng1 = Worksheets(2).Range("E2:G4")
        rng1.Copy

    wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False

'------------------------------------------------------------
    Set rng2 = Worksheets(2).Range("E6:G8")
        rng2.Copy

    wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
```

The reason I did it like this was because I want to cycle through the worksheets and I thought the best way would be to set the Worksheets(2) to a counter and then just cycle through a loop. I am going to try and only use one "Paste" as Storax suggested, but for now it works.